# dots that are not outliers in the boxplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, outliers

What are dots that are not outliers in the boxplot? I set outliers color to NA and I was able to remove most of the outliers except few.

Unfortunately I can not share the data as it is too big but I detailed an example code where I was trying to plot simple X and Y values.

Example code:

with outliers

```
qplot(x, y, data = file1, fill=z) + 
  geom_boxplot(outlier.colour = "black", outlier.shape = 1, outlier.size = 1) + 
  guides(fill=FALSE)
```

[image]

without outliers

```
qplot(x, y, data = file1, fill=z) + 
  geom_boxplot(outlier.colour = NA, outlier.shape = 1, outlier.size = 1) + 
  guides(fill=FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Try using `ggplot()` instead of `qplot()` in your first line?

Comment: you won't get help without code that can be run. I suggest you make a MWE or delete your question.